# fresh git clone shows modified as well as untracked files

Tags: git

EDITED : NEED TO SOLVE THIS FIRST:

Suppose, we have three system Linux ( case sensitive file system ) , MAC ( Not case sensitive ) and WINDOWS ( not case sensitive )

Now if someone on `LINUX` create a folder name `FORM` having files `a.php` , `b.php` , `c.php` and another folder name `form` having files `a.php` , `b.php` , `d.php` and pushes it to remote repo

Now when a user on `MAC` or `WINDOWS` clone the repo then how will `git` behave when handling `FORM` and `form` coming from `remote` because `MAC` and `WINDOWS` are case insensitive

**This problem may lead to problem I am facing described below**

Strange, I did a fresh `git clone` on my `MAC` ( tested on windows also ) and after that when I did `git status` it shows me 3 modified files and 3 untracked files

```
admin@admins-MacBook-Pro.local:~/Documents/myacademy$git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working  directory)

modified:   dev/Form/learn-trader-backup - Copy.php
modified:   dev/form/learn-trader.php
modified:   myacademy/images/Marketing_image.jpg

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

dev/Form/.learn-trader-foundation.php.swp
myacademy/de/FAQs-h%E4ufig_.pdf
myacademy/pt/FAQs-h%E4ufig.pdf
"v/M\303\251thodes.pdf"
```

When I did `git diff dev/form/learn-trader.php` , it actually showed me changes in the file .

`git crlf and mode false` does not work either.

Confused completely ..

Any help .

Thanks

Comment: Did you have git in that directory at some point?

Comment: @miqdadamirali : NO, not at all .. I have tried cloning in different folders .. :(

Comment: Why are there files named "...-backup - Copy" in this git repo? Sounds like someone doesn't understand how version control works.

Comment: @miqdadamirali I have updated the question with a problem which may solve my problem .. thanks

Comment: @JonathonReinhart :  have updated the question with a problem which may solve my problem .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before you clone into a folder make sure that there is no .git folder/soft link inside.

Comment: I have updated a question ... Can you please look into it .. I am sure it can resolve my issue

Comment: Are you using gitbash or cygwin ? It has defaults on converting line endings automatically . If a linux user uses linux eol and windows user clones the files and automatically converts eol's it can cause this thing to happen.

Comment: @Yoni if this is the issue, how do you fix it?